# Export unfinished image render

Tags: rendering, export, workflow

My render is "almost" complete...

[image]

It took almost 5 hours to render the center object, and from now on **Blender** will render nothing but white pixels of the **Emission** background all the way to the edges.

According to its estimations, **Blender** is going to spend 2 more hours rendering all the white background:

[image]

I don't need **Blender** to do this; I could easily bring the current data into an app like **Photoshop** and flatten to get the background to be white.

But I cannot save the image in its current state:

[image]

I cannot take screenshots and combine them either - it would take too long at 100% (Image is over 8000 pixels wide).

I'd like to restart my computer, or start another Blender project, etc... and would like not to have to wait 2 hours.

***Can I save the current, unfinished state of my render as an image if the elements I need have already been rendered?***

Comment: This looks like an instance where a Render Border would be useful, then compositing in the rest of the white.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can.  You will simply click the **X** beside the Render % or press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to cancel the render.  Then press <kbd>F3</kbd> as usual and it will save the rendered portion to your desired format/location.  The unrendered part will be black if saved as a JPEG and transparent if saved as an Alpha PNG.

Just to prove it ;) here you go:

[image]

Here's the canceled render of the default scene saved as a JPEG:

[image]

---

***EDIT:*** As was mentioned, Render Border can be useful in certain circumstances.  The problem is it's always rectangular (so it wouldn't have helped in this situation with a circular object) and it's usefulness is relegated to instances where you use multiple render layers.  *Otherwise, you can simply crop the render dimensions as close to the edges of your scene as possible which does the same thing.*

Comment: Great! Thanks! What is Render Border?

Comment: @MicroMachine - You're most welcome.  Render Border (Ctrl-B) draws a rectangle within the camera frame.  Anything inside the border gets rendered, anything outside is not.  The problem is you can't draw freehand shapes so it's usefulness is stunted.

Comment: Didn't work for me, they must have changed things since 2.9.

Comment: @Dakacha Yeah this was back in 2.78.  A lot has changed since then.  Weird that they wouldn't have made this possible though.